# By ID, Identify Highest Value, then assign that to all sharing ID

Tags: r

I have the following table, in each `EVENTID`, there are several `PERSONID`:

```
PERSONID    EVENTID  INJURYSCORE  DIABETES
222         A734     3            0
353         A734     4            1
45          B823     5            1
423         B283     2            1
232         B283     1            0
432         Y821     1            0
```

How do I make two new variables:

1. `maxscore` - which, per `EVENTID` marks a 1 to the `PERSONID` with the highest `INJURYSCORE`
2. `maxdiabetes` - per `EVENTID`, if any of the `PERSONID` have diabetes (diabetes = 1), a 1 is assigned to all other `PERSONID` in that `EVENTID`

Comment: Do any of the answers resolve your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `as.integer`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(EVENTID) %>%
    mutate(maxscore = as.integer(INJURYSCORE == max(INJURYSCORE)), 
           maxidiabetes = as.integer(any(DIABETES > 0)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
# Groups:   EVENTID [4]
#  PERSONID EVENTID INJURYSCORE DIABETES maxscore maxidiabetes
#     <int> <chr>         <int>    <int>    <int>        <int>
#1      222 A734              3        0        0            1
#2      353 A734              4        1        1            1
#3       45 B823              5        1        1            1
#4      423 B283              2        1        1            1
#5      232 B283              1        0        0            1
#6      432 Y821              1        0        1            0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(PERSONID = c(222L, 353L, 45L, 423L, 232L, 432L
), EVENTID = c("A734", "A734", "B823", "B283", "B283", "Y821"
), INJURYSCORE = c(3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L), DIABETES = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

### tidyverse

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(EVENTID) %>%
  mutate(
    maxscore = +(INJURYSCORE == max(INJURYSCORE)),
    maxdiabetes = +any(DIABETES > 0)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 6 x 6
#   PERSONID EVENTID INJURYSCORE DIABETES maxscore maxdiabetes
#      <int> <chr>         <int>    <int>    <int>       <int>
# 1      222 A734              3        0        0           1
# 2      353 A734              4        1        1           1
# 3       45 B823              5        1        1           1
# 4      423 B283              2        1        1           1
# 5      232 B283              1        0        0           1
# 6      432 Y821              1        0        1           0
```

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
datDT <- as.data.table(dat)
datDT[, maxscore := +(INJURYSCORE == max(INJURYSCORE)), by = EVENTID
  ][, maxdiabetes := +any(DIABETES > 0), by = EVENTID ][]
#    PERSONID EVENTID INJURYSCORE DIABETES maxscore maxdiabetes
# 1:      222    A734           3        0        0           1
# 2:      353    A734           4        1        1           1
# 3:       45    B823           5        1        1           1
# 4:      423    B283           2        1        1           1
# 5:      232    B283           1        0        0           1
# 6:      432    Y821           1        0        1           0
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
PERSONID    EVENTID  INJURYSCORE  DIABETES
222         A734     3            0
353         A734     4            1
45          B823     5            1
423         B283     2            1
232         B283     1            0
432         Y821     1            0")
```

Comment: For the data.table solution, you can create both columns simultaneously with `datDT[, `:=`(maxscore = +(INJURYSCORE == max(INJURYSCORE)), maxdiabetes = +any(DIABETES > 0)), by = EVENTID]`

Comment: Sure can, also with `[, c("maxscore","maxdiabetes") := .(val1, val2)]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option using `ave` within `transform`, e.g.,

```
transform(
  df,
  maxscore = +(ave(INJURYSCORE,EVENTID,FUN = max)==INJURYSCORE),
  maxdiabetes = ave(DIABETES,EVENTID,FUN = any)
)
```

which gives

```
  PERSONID EVENTID INJURYSCORE DIABETES maxscore maxdiabetes
1      222    A734           3        0        0           1
2      353    A734           4        1        1           1
3       45    B823           5        1        1           1
4      423    B283           2        1        1           1
5      232    B283           1        0        0           1
6      432    Y821           1        0        1           0
```